# Public variables for app components Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, global, public

In my Angular2 app I've got a "catalog" and a "cart" which are represented in my code via Catalog component + Catalog service and Cart component + Cart service.

I've got an array of products in my Catalog component and I want to add items from the array to another (initially empty) array which is Cart array.

My Catalog component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CatalogService } from './catalog.service';
import { CartComponent } from '../cart/cart.component';//I want to use the "cart" array initialized there in the Cart Component 

@Component({
  selector: 'catalog',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.scss']
})

export class CatalogComponent implements OnInit {
    catalog: any;
    image: any;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    prod: any;
    visible: boolean;

constructor(public catalogService: CatalogService){ } 

ngOnInit(){

    this.catalogService.getCatalogItems().subscribe(
        (data) => this.catalog = data
    );
}

getPrev(){
    this.catalog.push(this.catalog[0]);
    this.catalog.shift();
}

getNext(){
    this.catalog.unshift(this.catalog[this.catalog.length-1]);
    this.catalog.pop();
}

 togglePopup(prod){
    this.prod = prod;
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    this.image = prod.image;
    this.title = prod.title;
    this.description = prod.description;
}

   toCart(prod){
     this.cart.push(prod);//"cart" array of my Cart Component
   }

}
```

My Cart Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from './cart.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'cart',
    templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})

export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor (private cartService: CartService, public cart: Cart[]){}//by "public cart: Cart[]" I make it available from anywhere in my app

    ngOnInit(){
        this.cartService.getCartItems();
    }
}
```

My Catalog Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CatalogService {
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getCatalogItems() {
      return this.http.get('../catalog.json')//there are some items in the "catalog.json"
      .map((res) => res.json())
  }
}
```

My Cart Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
   constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getCartItems() {
      return this.http.get('../cart.json')//there are no items initially in the "cart.json", I want to add items from Catalog array to the initialized "cart : Cart[]" array
      .map(
        (res) => res.json()
      );
  }
}
```

Although I declared the global **Cart** variable ("public cart: Cart[]" in the Cart Component) and imported the Cart Component into Catalog Component, that **Cart** variable doesn't exist there (in my Catalog Component) and I can't add items from my catalog to the cart from there.

So, how to create one **Cart array** which would work for entire app? And if I add / remove smth out of there I want other components where I would use that **Cart** object to update its instance automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter passed to the constructor are **instance** values. You need an instance of that class to be able to access them. Importing doesn't help here at all.

Move the value to a service and inject the service where you want to access the value.

Provide the service only once (`@NgModule()` of `AppComponent`), then every component and service in your application will get the same service instance injected.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 1):

Placing a `public`, `private`, `protected`, or `readonly` modifier on a constructor parameter is syntactic shorthand for declaring a property with the same name and modifier and assigning it to the value passed for that parameter to the constructor when the class is instantiated.

These modifiers are a way to create instance members. They does not affect the global scope and their effects are in fact scoped at the class instance level.

For example, the following two class definitions are precisely equivalent

1.

```
class A {
  constructor(m: number) {
    this.m = m;
  }
  readonly m: number;
}
```

2.

```
class A {
  constructor(readonly m: number) { }
}
```

To achieve the global effect you would need to do something like

```
export class CartComponent {

  constructor (private cartService: CartService, cart: Cart[]) {
    window.cart = cart; // Make cart available from anywhere in my app.
  }
}
declare global {
  interface Window {
    cart: Cart[];
  }
}
```

But please do not do this! 
Do not use global variables!

You can use an angular service but there are more direct options that exist irrespective of what framework you are using.

For example

**app/shared-state.ts**

```
export default { 
  cart: undefined,
  // other shared stuff...
};
```

**app/cart.component.ts**

```
import sharedState from 'app/shared-state';

export class CartComponent {

  constructor (private cartService: CartService, public cart: Cart[]) {
    sharedState.cart = cart;
  }
}
```

This is still shared mutable state and should be avoided, but it does not pollute the global namespace.

Günter Zöchbauer's answer is probably closer to what you're looking for as you seem to be writing an angular application and it would be the conventional approach.

I wanted to answer the specific question, and clarify any misunderstanding related to the parameter property syntax, something which is not specific to angular.